# SVG Slider - Move dot only along SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I´ve created a circular SVG slider but I still have a problem on positioning the dot correctly. 
Have a look at the current result on Codepen:

HTML:

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="slider" width="300px" height="150px"> 
       <path id="sliderPath" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" d="M10,100a147,147,0,1,1,280,1"/>
       <circle id="dot" fill="white" cx="10" cy="100" r="14" /> 
    </svg>
```

JS:

```
var sliderPath = document.getElementById("sliderPath"),
box = sliderPath.getBBox(),
dot = document.getElementById("dot"),
W = box.width,
pathLength = sliderPath.getTotalLength();

Draggable.create(
    document.createElement('div'),
      { 
        type:'x',
        throwProps:true,
        bounds: { minX:0, maxX:W },
        trigger:dot,
        overshootTolerance:0,
        onDrag:update,
        onThrowUpdate:update
});

function update(){ 
  // Get x and y for dot.
  var P = sliderPath.getPointAtLength(this.x / W * pathLength);
  // Set dot.
  TweenLite.set(dot,{attr:{cx:P.x,cy:P.y}});
};
```

http://codepen.io/Yheeky/pen/xEbAbR

You can start dragging the dot and move the mouse from left to right. That works quite well, but I need to set the dot position more directly that the dot position is equal the mouse position but only along the path.
What do I need to change to get this kind of result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The example below shows a horizontal bar path. the path length of the bar and the path length of the sliderPath ratios are used to move the dot along the sliderPath.

The example is a little funky because I moved the svg so it was fully visible, but you should get an idea how it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slider@Semi Circle</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style='position:absolute;top:200px;left:200px;'>
<svg overflow=visible version="1.1" id="slider" width="300px" height="150px">
<path onmousedown=moveDotStart(evt) onmousemove=moveDot(evt) onmouseup=moveDotEnd(evt) onmouseout=moveDotEnd(evt) id="slideBar" stroke=lime opacity=.3 stroke-width=30 d="M10,100 L290,100" />
<path id="sliderPath" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width="5" d="M10,100a147,147,0,1,1,280,1"/>
<circle pointer-events="none"  id="dot" fill="blue" cx="10" cy="100" r="14" />
</svg>
</div>

<script>
var MoveDot=false
function moveDotStart(evt)
{
   MoveDot=true
}
function moveDot(evt)
{
    if(MoveDot==true)
    {
        var pathLength=sliderPath.getTotalLength()
        var barLength=slideBar.getTotalLength()
        var xCursor=evt.clientX-10-200
        var moveRatio=xCursor/barLength
        var dotPathLength=moveRatio*pathLength
        var dotPnt=sliderPath.getPointAtLength(dotPathLength)
        dot.setAttribute("cx",dotPnt.x)
        dot.setAttribute("cy",dotPnt.y)
    }

}

function moveDotEnd(evt)
{
  MoveDot=false
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```